# .NET Reactive merge lists

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive, reactiveui

I am new in reactive and I have no clue how to do it right.

```
var placeHolders= new SourceCache<Job, int>(j => j.id);
var jobs= new SourceCache<Job, int>(j => j.id);

placeHolders.AddOrUpdate(new Job() { id = -1, name = "A" IsPlaceHolder = true; });
placeHolders.AddOrUpdate(new Job() { id = -2, name = "B" IsPlaceHolder = true; });
placeHolders.AddOrUpdate(new Job() { id = -3, name = "C" IsPlaceHolder = true; });

jobs.AddOrUpdate(new Job() { id = 1, name = "A" IsPlaceHolder = false; });
jobs.AddOrUpdate(new Job() { id = 2, name = "B" IsPlaceHolder  = false; });
```

I want this list as result =>

```
Job() { id = 1, name = "A" IsPlaceHolder = false;
Job() { id = 2, name = "B" IsPlaceHolder  = false;
Job() { id = -3, name = "C" IsPlaceHolder  = true;
```

I tried a few functions like joins, selects and merge but got not the result I wanted

edit:
In this case I have 3 Placeholders that always have to be there.
So, if I add a Job for Place A and B, the Placeholders should be filtered and replaced with the added Jobs.
If a Job will be removed the placeholder should be listed again.

I tried something like this

```
placeHolders.Connect().Filter(p => jobs.Items.All(j => j.name != p.Name))
.Merge(jobs.Connect());
```

Now if I add or remove jobs, the list refreshes but the placholders don't.

Comment: These collections are Dynamic Data specific and whilst based on Rx need to be combined using Dynamic Data specific operators such as And, or Or which applies logic across multiple collections. However I am unable to attempt to answer the question as it's not clear what criteria produces the example result.

Comment: Do also consider reading [ask].

Comment: Please have a look, I edited it